# Why does java application deployed to GAE not update cron.xml?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron-task

I have a java application deployed to GAE for 3 years and until some weeks ago at each deployment the task list on GAE was updated to `cron.xml` entries.

in the last weeks the task list on GAE is **not updated** but I there isn't any errors in the deploy logs.

Has something changed in GAE platform?

Comment: what happens if you explicitly do just `AppCfg update_cron`?

Answer (score 0):

Appcfg update_con doesn't work, don't recognize cron.xml file.
However after clean the cron.xml from all entries, deployed the application and added again all the entries in the file and after submitted again the application, GAE has updated the task list correctly.
Thank for your support.